# python (flask) how to render html links from plain text input

Tags: python, html, sqlite, jinja2, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using python, flask, sqlalchemy/sqllite, jinja for my workflow.

I have a HEAP of text stored in the database and it's got paragraphs of plain text and in that text will be things like email@address.com, somedomain.com, www.somedomain.com, https://somedomain.com, https://www.somedomain.com, etc etc.

Is there a solution that exists for parsing the data as I load it and rendering it out as html links when I draw to the browser?  Currently it just renders as text without links being active.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to use an existing library, [python-textile](https://github.com/textile/python-textile), built for such a task.

For example:

```
import textile
from flask import Flask, render_template

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def index():

    plain_text = 'This text contains a link to https://stackoverflow.com'
    marked_up_text = textile.textile(plain_text)

    return render_template('layout.html', body=marked_up_text)
```

layout.html

```
{{body | safe}}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, looks promising.  I tried giving it a go and get the following errors.  I'm guessing the library might have an issue?

/venvLinux/lib/python3.6/site-packages/textile/core.py", line 228, in parse
    if text.strip() == '':
AttributeError: 'Post' object has no attribute 'strip'

Comment: @robster Your Post object isn't a `str`.

Comment: Thank you!  I'll look into this tonight.